# Calculating the nth derivative of $\frac{x}{x+1}$

Tags: factorial

I was asked to calculate the nth derivative of $f(x) =\frac{x}{x+1}$.
My solution:

$$ f'(x) = (x+1)^{-2}$$
$$f''(x) = (-2)(x+1)^{-3}$$
$$f'''(x) = (-2)(-3)(x+1)^{-4}$$
$$f^{n}(x) = n!(x+1)^{-(n+1)} . (-1)^{n+1}$$

I was confident that I got the right answer, but when I check the memo, it said the answer was the same as mine except for the $(-1)$ part. It said $(-1)^{n-1}$ instead of what I said. My question is is it still right anyways?

Comment: Wow. Three identical hints.

Comment: Yes, $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Thank you @michael. All I wanted to know.

Comment: Check the $n$-th derivate among the ones you wrote down: for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ you have $n-1$ copies of $-1$ in the product. And $-1^{n-1}=-1^{n+1}$ for all $n>1$ (and not only)...

Comment: You could use $a^n\times b^n = (a\times b)^n$ and $\left(\frac{1}{-1}\right)^n = (-1)^n$ to merge the last two factors, since they have the same exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{x}{x+1}=1-\dfrac1{x+1}$

In other words, your solution looks correct. Note that $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's right, you only have to realize that

$$(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1+2}=(-1)^{n-1} (-1)^2 = (-1)^{n-1}$$

As a suggestion, you could try to prove your expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$ in a more rigorous way using induction, if you haven't done that so far! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac x{x+1}=1-\frac1{x+1}=1-(x+1)^{-1}$$
So the $n$-th derivative is immediately seen to be
$$-(-1)(-2)\ldots(-n)(x+1)^{-n-1}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{(x+1)^{n+1}}$$
So you see that both your answer and the solution is right, but $(-1)^{n+1}$ seems to fit nicer with the exponent of $(x+1)$.